# Show files modified after a particular date ('find') in hierarchical format ('tree')

Tags: find, directory-structure, tree

I'm trying to view files modified before or after a certain date using the hierarchical output of the Unix `tree` command.

For example, I know that one can use `tree` to sort files chronologically and display their modification date:

```
tree --timefmt %Y-%m-%d -rt
```

I also know that one can use `find` to identify files that have been modified before or after a particular date:

```
find . -type f -newermt '2020-08-01'
```

or modified within a certain number of days:

```
find . -mtime -7
```

Is there a way to combine these `find` functionalities with a hierarchical output format?

Similarly, it would be great if a solution to the issue above could allow files greater than a particular file size to be shown in hierarchical format.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about directories which contain matched files, shall they be shown even if they do not match the criteria?

Comment: Hi Hauke, Thank you for your question.  Yes, it would be great to show the directories that contain the matched files even if they themselves do not meet the criteria.